# Javascript OOP, get father variable value

Tags: javascript, oop

I made a father class:

```
function MouseController(m,v) {
    this.model = m;
    this.view = v;
}

MouseController.prototype.mouseClick = function(x, y) {}
```

with two variables inside `this.model` and `this.view`.

Now I have a child class of this father:

```
DragController.prototype = new MouseController();
function DragController() {
    MouseController.call(this);
}
```

How can I access to father variable `this.model` and `this.view` from child class ?

Comment: `this.model` _should_ be the same in prototype methods as it is in own methods.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure MouseController inherits from DragController properly.

```
DragController.prototype = MouseController.prototype;
```

Then use:

```
this.model
this.view
```

The properties are inherited :-)

Make sure the arguments are passed to the base class:

```
function DragController(m, v) {
    MouseController.call(this, m, v);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GarryPas/ku4p4332/3/

Comment: The statement `DragController.prototype.constructor= MouseController.prototype.constructor;` will return `MouseController` as the constructor of `DragController` instances. Also the statement `DragController.prototype = MouseController.prototype;` is not the way to get prototypical subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

When you make the call `MouseController.call(this)` inside the `DragController`'s constructor, you are setting the newly instantiated `DragController` object's (`this`) properties `model` and `view`.

So these properties are directly accessible through the current instance i.e. as `this.model` and `this.view`.

Of course since (A) you don't pass anything to the `new MouseController()` when you create the `DragController.prototype` and (B) you don't pass anything to the `MouseController.call(this)` call, both `this.model` and `this.view` end up being `undefined`.

You have two options to assign values to `model` and `view` upon instantiation.

### Option 1

Pass values to `MouseController` when you create the `DragController.prototype`:

```
 DragController.prototype = new MouseController(<default model value for all objects>, <default view value for all objects>);
```

With Option 1, all  newly create `DragController` objects will have the same initial values for the `model` and `view` properties and there is no need to call `MouseController.call()` in the `DragController` constructor function.

### Option 2

Pass parameters to the `DragController` constructor and handle them as:

SubOption 2.1: use them directly to assign the corresponding properties of the newly instantiated object

OR

SubOption 2.2: pass them to the call `MouseController.call()`:

```
function DragController(m,v) {
    // Suboption 2.1
    MouseController.call(this,m,v);
    --OR--
    // Suboption 2.2
    MouseController.call(this);
    this.model = m;
    this.view = v;

}
```

Either way, methods inherited from the parent `MouseController` through the prototype chain, will have access just fine to `this.model` and `this.view`.

### Minor detail

No matter which way you go, you might want to also fix the results of getting the property `.constructor` of your `DragController` instances. Now for example if you create a new `DragController`:

```
dc = new DragController('foo', 'bar');
dc.constructor; // returns 'MouseController' instead of `DragController`
```

To fix this, you should add a statement:

```
DragController.prototype.constructor=DragController;
```